# OrderByRaw en Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy creando una aplicación que filtra productos.

Quiero agregar este fragmento de consulta a mi `$productos = $ productos-> newQuery ();`

Estoy usando `$productos = $productos->newQuery();` Porque estoy consultando con filtros. Ejemplo:

```
$products = $products->newQuery();

  if ($request->has('brand') && !empty($brand)) {
            $products->where('brand', '=', $brand);
        }

        if ($request->has('size') && !empty($size)) {
            $products->whereHas('stocks', function($query) use ($size) {
                $query->where('size', '=', $size);
            });
        }
```

Quiero añadir esta consulta

```
 $best_sellers = OrderItem::select('product_id')->groupBy('product_id')->orderByRaw('SUM(quantity) DESC')->limit(2)->get();
```

La consulta de arriba ya la he usado en otro método y funciona. Necesito una consulta similar para integrarla en la query de $productos.

La he intentado de estas dos maneras.

1.

```
$products->whereHas('order_items', function($query) {
                        $query->select('product_id')->groupBy('product_id')->orderByRaw('SUM(quantity) DESC');

});
```

2. 

```
$products->with('order_items', function ($query) {
                            $query->select('product_id')->groupBy('product_id')->orderByRaw('SUM(quantity)', 'desc');
                        });
```

Pero no funciona de ninguna de las dos maneras. Alguna idea?

Comment: Intenta pasando en el select la pk de `order_items`, por ejemplo: `select('id_order_items','product_id')`

Comment: No me ha funcionado :(